Sizing string light support poles so they don't bend
Looking guidance on how to size out string light post so the pole doesn't bend/sag from light tension during a 24ft mid span, but with tension from the both sides of the wire within 45deg of each other). Planning on tensioned 1/16 306 stainless attached via tie wraps to the standard 1W bulb string lights (12 lights per 24').
I am wondering if I can get away with 3/4 EMT or should size up to 1-1/2?  Looking for a cheap and rigid solution to this.
Plan is 8 feet of pole exposed with 2 feet below ground in an upsized pvc overshell that goes down about 3 feet (last foot packed with a  weep hole drilled at 2 ft). Its clay and bedrock mix that is well compacted, so not worried about blowing out the compacted soil.

mid-span or end span posts?  cable will sag no matter what, because gravity. how much actual tension? what is the ground made of.. two feet of bedrock is much better than two feet of sand.

Hi Jason, read it and realized it was ambiguous in the paragraph that it should be the poles not bending/sagging and not the worried about the lights (except want to keep sagging under 2 feet deflection in each run.
I calculated just under  31lb (130 N() force  for a 2 foot sag/24 ft run and 1.5 kg.  With two runs 45 deg out, the RSS means would be sqrt(2)  of both legs, so 44 lbf at the end of a 8 foot arm.  I just can't find tables for schedule 40 rigid and EMT

@ChucktheDuck please do not write information in a comment ... update the question instead

Just confirming the angle between the two wires is 45 degrees like between south and south-west. and not 135  like north and south-east

I have a 1" galvanized iron pipe 10' tall (about 8' above a support base) doing a similar job and it still bends a bit. 3/4" EMT is way too floppy. I'm not sure I understand your scenario ("during a 24ft mid span"? "both sides of the wire"?), so I haven't posted an answer.

Hi all, sorry for confusion.  The worst case scenario is the rod supporting 2 segments of 24 ft of string lights that are 8 feet up and allowed to sag 2 ft (this gives tension calculation). The segments are 45° away from each other so the rss tension is actually 2*cos(22.5°). I made a mistake by using 45° as the RSS max angle force and not halfway between.  I will clean up question later on when time permits, will be weekend I think.

As a span apprently "3/4" x 48" EMT weight limit without bending is 100lb"
But as a span it's supported at both ends,  So if supported at only one end halve both numbers. 24" and 50lb. Now you have 4 times the stick-out length, so the force is quartered, 12lb8oz.
Not nearly enough, Maybe try RMC, or iron pipe instead.

I don't understand your first sentence (fragment). Please revise that for clarity.

I was surprised but then not when I went to HD and put weight at the end of 3/4.  It seems that 1-1/4 EMT is much stronger, but I went with 1-1/4" RMC and it hold the weight well without bending.  I can't find any manufacturers bending modulus to calculate the weight before substantial bending starts.
